# Automatically translate web page

Tags: javascript, php, internationalization

How can I automatically translate my web page when I entered it.

This is my translator there is connected to my dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'da', includedLanguages: 'da,de,el,en,es,fi,fr,it,ja,ko,nl,no,pl,ru,sv,uk,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-32978177-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

I want it to translate automatically from Danish (da) to English (en). I have read about this function:

http://www.blabla.com/#googtrans(da|en)

Where should I implement it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a div called google_translate_element which is mentioned in the first script like this:

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
Here is the Area where Google fetches the part to be translated
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

This second script generates a nice tiny language selection :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

And if you wish to hide the resulting Google translation bar (first script) :

```
<style>
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
} body { top: 0px !important; }
.goog-tooltip {
    display: none !important;
}
.goog-tooltip:hover {
    display: none !important;
}
.goog-text-highlight {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

both scripts can go in the `<head>` section, they will work if in the `<body>` tag but this can look untidy unless you put them at the end... which is not a good idea because translation options should be available *before* the entire page renders in the browser.

You will need to add a line to the  tag in the position you want the language drop-down box to appear, eg: from the end of the existing `<head>` tag,  this is the `<div>` tag that Claudio Kemp pointed out is missing in your code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'da', includedLanguages: 'da,de,el,en,es,fi,fr,it,ja,ko,nl,no,pl,ru,sv,uk,zh-CN,zh-TW', 
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-32978177-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</div>
<h1>My heading</h1>
```

The `<div>` code above given by [google's webmaster translation tool] (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/), there are 3 different display options which affect only the `<div>` code: tabbed, inline and automatic (which appears to not work) - with vertical, horizonal and drop-down display options for each. Your code uses the tabbed option.

You might want to change the code you included to translate to any language rather than just those listed, and to show the language option at the top rather than the bottom of the page so the user sees them sooner.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'da', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_RIGHT, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ur', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'it'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="50cedd4c399ba41-3cc63c25c261b71e-g03cc961129fb2947-10"></meta>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: this code has a unique content ID at the top, which isn't needed anymore, and I think may be specific to the site using it

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT},
      'google_translate_element'
    );
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```