# Translate Asp.net web page with custom translation

Tags: asp.net, language-translation, microsoft-translator, google-translator-toolkit

I am developing an Asp.Net website that supports **multi-language functionality**. I have used server-side controls along with client-side controls. Server-side controls might include any Third-Party controls. What I want is **I want to translate a web page with a specific language**, Let's say Turkish. I found , **Microsoft provides an API** to convert whole web site into any language. It working fine for me. What I want is when page loads it automatically translated into Turkish language.

**NOTE:** *I dont want to select Turkish from the drop down menu to translate.*

One more thing what I want, is to translate some custom tags as per my translation not as per API.

How can I achieve above scenario?

Here are reference links those I exposed"

[Automatically translate web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541760/automatically-translate-web-page)

[Microsoft Bing Translator](https://www.bing.com/widget/translator?ref=MSTWidget)

Any one who already faced this one may suggest. Any small idea will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try Google Translator API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. @GunjalRay Any help with link or code will be helpful.